# How to revert selection from radio button after pressing add button

Tags: java, netbeans, radio-button

So, I have this class project : [Class Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuyGd.jpg)

and I want to set all text and radio button selection to be empty after I click the button "Tambah" (it mean add).

I can do it with the text field and text area using this method :

```
private void kosongkanText(){
txtIdPelanggan.setText("");
txtNamaPelanggan.setText("");
Talamat.setText("");
txtNotlp.setText("");
```

but how to do it to radio button?. already try this, and not working :

```
groupJenisKelamin.setSelected(null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get what is your question, but if you want to uncheck the radio button that already checked you can use setChecked(false)
for example :

```
private boolean flagpria = false;
private boolean flagwanita = false;


rdbtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rdbtnMale.isChecked()) {
                if (!flagmale) {
                    rdbtnPria.setChecked(true);
                    rdbtnWanita.setChecked(false);
                    flagpria = true;
                    flagwanita = false;
                } else {
                    flagpria = false;
                    rdbtnPria.setChecked(false);
                    rdbtnWanita.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    rdbtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rdbtnFemale.isChecked()) {
                if (!flagfemale) {
                    rdbtnWanita.setChecked(true);
                    rdbtnPria.setChecked(false);
                    flagwanita = true;
                    flagpria = false;
                } else {
                    flagwanita = false;
                    rdbtnWanita.setChecked(false);
                    rdbtnPria.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

those code above mean you have 2 radio button if you check "pria" in "wanita" this code will uncheck it

Comment: I meant to uncheck the radio button after I click the add button. I can pick between 2 radio button. all I want is all field is back to default after I click the add button and the values inserted to database.

Comment: actually you can use the same logic above using setChecked(false)